# How can I Make appear Button above a Pygame Circle?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying for a long time to try to put a button above a multicoloured circle but I can't, when I do it the button is covered by the circle, I have tried several things but none of them work.

```py
import pygame, math
from pygame import font
pygame.init()
def lerp_color(colors, value):
    fract, index = math.modf(value)
    color1 = pygame.Color(colors[int(index) % len(colors)])
    color2 = pygame.Color(colors[int(index + 1) % len(colors)])
    return color1.lerp(color2, fract)

def button(screen, position, text):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Anton", 50)
    text_render = font.render(text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
    x, y, w , h = text_render.get_rect()
    x, y = position
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (150, 150, 150), (x, y), (x + w , y), 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (150, 150, 150), (x, y - 2), (x, y + h), 5)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (100, 100, 100), (x, y, w , h))
    return screen.blit(text_render, (x, y))

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800)) 
screen2 = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
b1 = button(screen,(310,200), "Faster")

variable = 1



run = True
while run:
    
    clock.tick(60)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    screen.blit(b1)
    colors = [(000,000,000), (255,0,0), (000,255,000), (000,000,255), (255,0,255), (000,255,255), (255,255,000), (255,000,255)]
    value = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time) / 1000
    current_color = lerp_color(colors, value)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen2, current_color, screen.get_rect().center, 500) 


    print(value)
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must draw the button after the circle:

```py
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    colors = [(000,000,000), (255,0,0), (000,255,000), (000,000,255), (255,0,255), (000,255,255), (255,255,000), (255,000,255)]
    value = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time) / 1000
    print(value)
    current_color = lerp_color(colors, value)
    
    screen.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen2, current_color, screen.get_rect().center, 500) 
    button(screen,(310,200), "Faster")
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Note, The instruction `screen.blit(b1)` does not do what you expect. It only cuases an error. [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blits) does not return an object, it only returns the rectangular area that was affected by the operation. Therefore the `button` returns a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object and `bl` is just a rectangle.